# Reference generated R class from Android code shared between different build flavors

Tags: android, gradle

My question is similar to this unanswered one:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20572321/sharing-resources-with-gradles-builds-using-differing-package-names

I'm trying to convert a bunch of Android projects that all share the same code base (but of course different package names) into one multi-flavor Android Studio/gradle project.  Each app from before will become a build flavor in the new project.  I exported from Eclipse and imported to Android Studio, and got it to build.

My problem is that when I refactored the source code from com.company.appname to com.company.common, with an "appname" flavor, now the R file is still com.company.appname.R.  I can't reference that from the common code because the next flavor will have com.company.otherappname.R.

Here's my build.gradle if that's helpful.

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 9

        testPackageName "com.company.common.common"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.common.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            packageNameSuffix ".debug"
        }
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        AppName {
            packageName "com.company.appname"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    some libraries and stuff
}
```

I can paste the manifest if that would help.  I can hack a solution using reflection, but that is nasty and gives up all compile time safety when referencing resources, which I would like to avoid.  Is the only other solution to not refer to the R class from any common code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since all flavors share code, the R classes for all flavors are all generated in the same package. It's the package that's declared in `src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

The build system will handle this by making all flavors have their own package name but the R class being the same everywhere. (The fact that usually the R class is generated in the package declared in the manifest is just a default that can be overriden)

The package used by the R class will not be used or referenced when identifying the app on the device or in the Play Store. In that case it's the packageName declared in the flavor that is used.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you.  I just had my main manifest still naming the com.company.appname package, rather than com.company.common.  I changed that and added a manifest in appname/src and everything looks to be fine.  Thanks again!